# charting class library that can handle with big datasets

Tags: c#

im looking for a charting class library, that can handle with very big datasets (2 Millions points per second for example) free or not free doesnt mather.. are there any libraries, that can plot 2d and 3d ?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Nevron](http://www.nevron.com) has in its latest release so called [Clustered Point Series](http://www.nevron.com/Products.ChartFor.NET.WhatsNew.aspx). With these they won't paint a dot for each dataPoint. Instead they will be grouped and only paint where you got visual differences. Thous making it much faster to display then using a standard point series.

If you're going to work with WPF you should take a lookt into the [Dynamic Data Display](http://dynamicdatadisplay.codeplex.com), cause they say they would also be quite fast by thousands of dataPoints.